# solidity, nodejs ethereum events not getting emitted or not reveived by the server

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, truffle, metamask

In my smart contract I have following paymentDone event which is emitted and the server is supposed to catch it and change the database but for some reasone either the event is not getting emitted or it is not recieved by the server.
I am using truffle and metamask for testing and the transaction is getting completed as per the metamask log

Smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';

contract PaymentProcessor {

    address public admin;
    IERC20 public dai;

    event PaymentDone(
        address payer,
        uint amount,
        uint paymentId,
        uint date
    );

    constructor(address adminAddress, address daiAddress) {
        admin = adminAddress;
        dai = IERC20(daiAddress);
    }

    function pay(uint amount, uint paymentId) external {
        dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, admin, amount);
        emit PaymentDone(msg.sender, amount, paymentId, block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Server function:

```
const listenToEvent = () => {
    console.log("event");
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:9545");
    const networkId = "5777";

    const paymentProcessor = new ethers.Contract(
        PaymentProcessor.networks[networkId].address,
        PaymentProcessor.abi,
        provider
    );

    paymentProcessor.on('PaymentDone', async (payer, amount, paymentId, date) => {
        console.log("test");
        console.log(`
            from ${payer} 
            amount ${amount} 
            paymentId ${paymentId} 
            date ${(new Date(date.toNumber() * 1000)).toLocaleString()}
        `);

        console.log(paymentId);
        const payment = await Payment.findOne({id: paymentId});
        console.log(payment);

        if(payment) {
            payment.paymentDone = true;
            await payment.save();
        }
    });    
}

listenToEvent();
```

Comment: r u sure it is 9545. ganache is running or 7545

Comment: i am using truffle account which is running on 9545 so this should be correct right?